# What is this? A 3D-printed puzzle

Tags: visual

(I was going to put this on the puzzling meta board before putting it live just to see how everyone reacted to it because I'm not sure how well it would be received, but for some reason I can't ask a question there right now so I figure it's a sign, and I'll go ahead and put it live)

I recently obtained a 3D printer and have been experimenting with it. I printed out... well... something, and after scraping away the support structures I figured it could make for an interesting puzzle. One where you can't simply use google to search for the clues needed to solve it.

I'm looking for the specific name of this, you won't get credit for the solution by saying something like "it's an artwork!" or "it's a piece of landscape!" or "it's a body part!" I'm very picky and I want specifics.

So tell me, puzzlers: What is this?

[image: mystery print]

> It's probably bad form to give a hint before I even start, but just in case anyone's interested in 3d printing, there's a website called Thingiverse which is a phenomenal source of free 3d printable files, and that's where I got this.

Comment: Is it a upside down Chess Bishop and Knight pieces merged in one?

Comment: Not quite, but I suppose if you printed out a bunch of similar things you could USE it as a chess bishop.

Comment: Looks like the comet the Philea lander is on.

Comment: So now that someone's solved it, I'm a bit relieved that it wasn't too hard. What do you guys think of this style of puzzle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it:

> An upside down bust of Sappho?
> [image]
> Specifically the one on the right hand side.

Comment: Indeed it is! Congratulations!

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> An upside down bust of Marianne?
>  [image]

Comment: OOh, very close! It is in fact an upside down bust but that's not the figure.

Answer (score 2):

> [image]

Here's a better picture for those of you confused about alexmc's answer. (whoever printed that one either chose to do it in multiple parts, probably because they scaled up the size and their print area could only handle so much, or they had a print error that caused the base to slide once it reached a certain height or something like that)